# If check box in sheet 1 is true, delete the row with same values in sheet 2 Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A sheet called 'Report' uses a query to import data from multiple sheets. All sheets but one get data from other files.

There is a sheet called 'SavedDB' to which I can save rows that I want to keep in case they are eliminated from their original source. I got this to work with the help of other posts.

I created two buttons, save and delete, and every row has a checkbox associated with each button.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSdbB.png)

Whenever the user clicks the button Save in the sheet 'Report', the script copies all the rows that are checked TRUE to the sheet SavedDB, it will then be imported by a query in 'Formatted Saved' which in turn is imported by a query in 'Report'

Now I'm trying to implement the reverse process. When the user clicks Delete all the rows in which the column delete is checked should be removed from 'SavedDB'.

The deleted row has to be an exact match in every column except the first 6, which are not exported to 'SavedDB' in the first place.

This is what I have so far:

```js
function deleteRows() {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Report'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('D:D'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('SavedDB'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var dataNew =[];
 

  //Condition check in D:D; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'true') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,7,1,25).getValues());
  
  
 }
 }
  
 //####THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK###
  
  //GET ALL NON-EMPTY ROWS ON 'SavedDB IN THE ARRAY dataNew
  
  //COMPARE BOTH ARRAYS data AND dataNew
  
  // ADD ALL THE UNIQUE ROWS, AND IF A ROW IS REPEATED DISCARD IT ALTOGETHER
  
  //SAVE NEW VALUES TO 'savedDB'

 
  
 //######
  
  
  //changes the check boxes back to false(unchecked)
 var resetRange = sheet.getRange('E3:E');
 var values = resetRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] == true) {
        values[i][j] = false; // Modified
      }
    }
  }
resetRange.setValues(values); 
  
  
  
}
```

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what else you want but this might be a better start.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Report');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,4,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('SavedDB');
  var data = [];
  for (i=0; i<vA.length;i++) {
    if (vA[i][0]=='TRUE') {
      data.push(sh.getRange(i+1,7,1,25).getValues()[0]);
    }
  }
}
```